# Where kafka stores partitions for the topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I installed kafka on a linux server. I defined a topic with a few partitions. I know that each partition is mapped to a physical file on disk, but I don't know where it is.
Where are the partition files saved ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your config/server.properties you'll find a section on "Log Basics". The property `log.dirs` is defining where your logs/partitions will be stored on disk.

Answer (score 7):

By default on Linux it is stored in `/tmp/kafka-logs`. If you will navigate to this folder you will see something like this:

- recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
- replication-offset-checkpoint
- topic-0
- msg-0
- msg-1

Which means that you have two topics (`topic` which has 1 partition and `msg` which has 2).

As it was noted by Ludd, you can find the location inside `config/server.properties` file by looking for `log.dirs`.

Comment: thanks for this! i assumed only errors would be shown in the kafka-logs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic test
```

you will get output

```
Topic:test  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,2,0
```

now try going to `\config file`

```
cat server.properties
```

and search for `broker_id`

if `broker_id` matches with leader number then topic partition is stored in that broker

Answer (score 0):

I have started **Kafka standalone server** with default properties in **Windows** and found the **Topic** and **partitions** details in the below directory

```
C:\tmp\kafka-logs
```

[image]